# Referencing my css class as objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option that, when selected, is supposed to show the appropriate sections. By default everything is set to `display:none`.

In this instance, if June is selected, then I want it to show all divs that have the class of `june`.

```
 $('#list').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "june") {
         $('.june').css('display', 'block')
     }
 });
```

The code works as it should. However, I would like to write this more efficiently because I plan on adding additional months. To that end, how would I go about doing something along the lines of this:

```
$('#list').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == {
            thischosenmonth
        }) {
        $('.{thischosenmonth}').css('display', 'block')
    }
});
```

where `thischosenmonth` coincides with the month chosen by the user?

Comment: You can use variables inside of the jQuery selectors!
$('.'+userInput).css('display', 'block')

How are you retrieving the user input?

Comment: How about `$('.' + $(this).val()).show();` inside your change event? Instead of using the IF for each one? If they all had the same class too, like `class='june month'`, then you could call `$('.month').hide()` first to hide all other months that don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all months to `display:none;` first (I will use `hide()` for that), then use the value of the dropdown to set `display:block;` for the corresponding month selection (I will use `show()` for that). So if the HTML looked something like this (with more months obviously):

```
<select id='sel-month'>
  <option disabled selected>Choose a Month</option>
  <option value='january'>January</option>
  <option value='february'>February</option>
  <option value='march'>March</option>
</select>
<div class='month january'>This is the January box.</div>
<div class='month february'>This is the February box.</div>
<div class='month march'>This is the March box.</div>
```

You could use a script like this to show the corresponding month's information when the dropdown is changed:

```
$('#sel-month').change(function(){
    $('.month').hide();
  $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yk44zbq/